XSLT separates keys as lookups for multiple child nodes
Apologies for my amateur XML / XSLT knowledge - still learning. I hope I've provided enough detail below.
I've recently learned about how an xsl "key" can be used a lookup. I'm now trying to apply it to a file with multiple separate child nodes, which should each have their own separate lookup, but I can't figure out how to put the key statement within a for-each loop.
Simple example INPUT:
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<file>
<record>
    <data>
        <item>2</item>
        <item>4</item>
        <item>6</item>
    </data>
    <names>
        <person><id>1</id><name>Anton</name></person>
        <person><id>2</id><name>Bruce</name></person>
        <person><id>3</id><name>Chris</name></person>
        <person><id>4</id><name>Dirk</name></person>
        <person><id>5</id><name>Erik</name></person>
        <person><id>6</id><name>Fred</name></person>
    </names>
</record>
<record>
    <data>
        <item>1</item>
        <item>2</item>
        <item>5</item>
    </data>
    <names>
        <person><id>1</id><name>Sue</name></person>
        <person><id>2</id><name>Jen</name></person>
        <person><id>3</id><name>Jill</name></person>
        <person><id>4</id><name>Jane</name></person>
        <person><id>5</id><name>Maria</name></person>
        <person><id>6</id><name>Mary</name></person>
    </names>
</record>
</file>

The idea is to use the data/item value to look up the corresponding names/person/id within the same record node and return the name.
Desired output
<results>
   <result>
      <item>2</item>
      <name>Bruce</name>
   </result>
   <result>
      <item>4</item>
      <name>Dirk</name>
   </result>
   <result>
      <item>6</item>
      <name>Fred</name>
   </result>
</results>
<results>
   <result>
      <item>1</item>
      <name>Sue</name>
   </result>
   <result>
      <item>2</item>
      <name>Jen</name>
   </result>
   <result>
      <item>5</item>
      <name>Maria</name>
   </result>
</results>

However, ny understanding is that the key needs to be at the top level, but when I then use the key to 'look up' the value, it returns all entries that match the item number (from all child nodes).
XSLT:
    <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:key name="k1" match="file/record/names/person" use="id" />

<xsl:template match="file/record">
    <results>
        <xsl:for-each select="data/item">
            <result>
                <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
                <xsl:copy-of select="key('k1', .)/name"/>
            </result>           
        </xsl:for-each>
    </results>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>


The incorrect result is that it doubles up on the names, because it has found multiple entries in the entire document that match.
Incorrect output:
<results>
   <result>
      <item>2</item>
      <name>Bruce</name>
      <name>Jen</name>
   </result>
   <result>
      <item>4</item>
      <name>Dirk</name>
      <name>Jane</name>
   </result>
   <result>
      <item>6</item>
      <name>Fred</name>
      <name>Mary</name>
   </result>
</results>
<results>
   <result>
      <item>1</item>
      <name>Anton</name>
      <name>Sue</name>
   </result>
   <result>
      <item>2</item>
      <name>Bruce</name>
      <name>Jen</name>
   </result>
   <result>
      <item>5</item>
      <name>Erik</name>
      <name>Maria</name>
   </result>
</results>

Any idea on how I can do an independent key / lookup for each record?
Many thanks for your expert advice.
Kind regards,
AJ

Are you really limited to XSLT 1? In XSLT 2 and later the key function takes an optional third argument of a node whose subtree the lookup is restricted to. So with XSLT 2 or later/an XSLT 2 or higher processor you could use e.g. key('k1', ., ancestor::record).

I checked and the tool I'm using (SAP Cloud Integration) supports XSLT 3.0, so I was able to change the code to   <xsl:copy-of select="key('k1', .,ancestor::record)/name"/>   and it worked perfectly. Thank you so much for your advice, Martin. Doing my best to learn as much as possible from guidance like this.

In your future questions about XSLT please state which version of XSLT your processor supports (you can simply add the xslt-3.0 tag to the generic xslt one).

Noted - and thanks.

You just need to include the unique identifier of the record element in the key's value:
XSLT 1.0
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:key name="k1" match="person" use="concat(id, '|', generate-id(ancestor::record))" />

<xsl:template match="/file">
    <results>
        <xsl:for-each select="record">
            <xsl:variable name="record-id" select="generate-id()" />
            <xsl:for-each select="data/item">
                <result>
                    <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
                    <xsl:copy-of select="key('k1', concat(., '|', $record-id))/name"/>
                </result>           
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </results>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>


Thank you again Michael, I wasn't aware of the generate-id command (still very much a novice). This is really helpful for me to expand my knowledge.

<xsl:copy-of select="key('k1', .,ancestor::record)/name"/> solved the issue for me, using XSLT 3.0 (thanks Martin).
Thanks to you all for your feedback and sharing of expertise - very much appreciated.

This is quite hard to achieve in XSLT 1.0, since as you say, the scope of the key is document-wide. In principle, so long as your processor offers the xx:node-set() extension, you can copy a subtree to a new document in a variable, and if the context item is a node within that variable, the key function will search the subtree. But of course it will return the copied node identified by the key, not the original.
Later XSLT versions offer much more flexibility. In fact, in XSLT 3.0 you can use maps instead of keys, which allow you for example to define an index that spans multiple documents.

quite hard to achieve in XSLT 1.0 No it isn't.

OK, not hard if you know how, just very messy.

That's a matter of opinion (mine differs).
